# Where on Ruusan was the Valley of the Jedi constructed in relation to the detonated thought bomb?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-bane

I know that the **Valley of the Jedi** (or **Valley of the Souls**) was built by the Jedi Knight, [Johun Othone](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Johun_Othone) to memorialize the Jedi that gave their lives fighting the Sith in the [Seventh Battle of Ruusan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Seventh_Battle_of_Ruusan). According to the Wookieepedia article on [Ruusan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ruusan/Legends) (*emphasis mine*):

> ...a Jedi Knight named Johun Othone petitioned the Galactic Senate to construct a grand mausoleum containing the one-hundred fallen warriors called The Valley of the Jedi, ***located on the former location of Olmondo***.

And, according to the [Olmondo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Olmondo) article:

> Olmondo was the former capital city of the planet Ruusan.

However, the article on the [Valley of the Jedi](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Valley_of_the_Jedi) says this:

> The **Valley of the Jedi** or the **Valley of the Souls** was the site of the Seventh Battle of Ruusan, the last battle of the New Sith Wars and a thousand years before the Battle of Yavin.

After reading through the events of that battle in the novel, [Darth Bane: Path of Destruction](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Bane:_Path_of_Destruction), it certainly doesn't sound to me like the thought bomb was detonated in, around, or under a city (even an "abandoned" one). According to that telling of the story:

> [Lord Kaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skere_Kaan) led the Sith Lords of the [Brotherhood of Darkness](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Brotherhood_of_Darkness/Legends) into a system of caves to protect themselves from the threat of aerial attacks from [Lord Hoth's](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hoth_(Jedi_Lord)) [Army of Light](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Army_of_Light/Legends). It was in these caves that the Sith Lord performed the ritual of the [thought bomb](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thought_bomb) and detonated it when Lord Hoth confronted them in an effort to ensure that such a weapon wouldn't be used someplace that would result in a greater loss of life.

On the other hand, Wookieepedia also has *this* to say about the monument:

> The Valley of the Jedi then became a concentrated area of Force energy called a [Force nexus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_nexus), and is widely believed to be the most powerful Force nexus in the entire galaxy.

This makes it sound to me like the "remnants" of the thought bomb were in, around, or under the Valley of the Jedi itself, simply because of what those "remnants" actually *are*. Additionally, according to the [Dark Forces](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Forces_(novellas)) novellas, when [Kyle Katarn](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kyle_Katarn/Legends) later comes to the Valley of the Jedi to confront the Dark Jedi [Jerec](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jerec_(Inquisitor)), he is able to:

> release the imprisoned and tortured spirits of the Jedi and Sith that had been trapped and tortured by the thought bomb's detonation centuries earlier.

There is very little mention of the actual, physical remnants of the thought bomb in those stories, even though much is discussed about its effects. The Bane Trilogy, however, is quite specific about what remained after the thought bomb detonated:

> The souls of 100 Jedi and every Sith Lord participating in the ritual were trapped in a silvery ovoid that was created by the ritual and was left over when the thought bomb was detonated. Several characters - Darovit, Zannah, Bane, and others - actually saw or even touched the orb after the detonation.

So, I'm left wondering about the relational positioning of exactly *where* the thought bomb was actually detonated and the eventual construction site of the Valley of the Jedi. ***Was the Valley of the Jedi built on top of the site of the thought bomb's detonation, or is/was Olmondo in another location entirely?*** Please provide source links/references in answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cross-posting a bit from my answer on [the related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245840/21154). Cutscenes in Jedi Knight I and II show the source of the Force energy in the Valley of the Jedi to be the large dome in the center. In the (Legends-)canonical, "good" ending, Kyle Katarn frees the energy from the dome:

[image: Screengrab from Dark Forces II: Jedi Knight showing a rocky dome with energy streaming out]
(source: cutscene from [Dark Forces II: Jedi Knight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmD-HlPAVTw))

This is confirmed to be a depiction of freeing the souls from the thought bomb in *Book of Sith*:

> Kyle Katarn, one of my students, unfolded the thought bomb's vortex at Ruusan and freed the spirits that had been trapped inside for more than a thousand years. —Luke

(*Book of Sith*, p70)

Out-of-universe, the Valley is confirmed to be built on the location of the battle itself in *The Essential Reader's Companion*:

> The planet is home to the fabled Valley of the Jedi, site of an ancient battle between a Jedi Army of Light and the Brotherhood of Darkness.

(*The Essential Reader's Companion*, p27)

So, the simplest interpretation is that the monument was built on the site of the Thought Bomb. This makes sense geographically as well - the thought bomb was detonated in a series of caves, which is where the Valley is located in the game.

As for the location of Olmondo, this claim is unsourced on Wookieepedia, and I can't find any results for "Olmondo" in the second or third Darth Bane novel on Google Books. From Wookieepedia material on the Bouncers and the *Essential Reader's Companion* summary of *Dark Forces: Rebel Agent*, it looks like Olmondo is where Morgan Katarn met the Bouncers, who *then* led him to the Valley of the Jedi. This seems like a mistake by an editor on Wookieepedia, and Olmondo is somewhere else.

Comment: My only "hesitation", if you can really call it that, is that the quote you provided from *The Essential Reader's Companion* (I've not seen or read that particular reference source before - I suppose it's more "essential" than I would have surmised) only says "***an** ancient battle*", not *explicitly* the Seventh Battle of Ruusan. I, like you, believe this is a reasonable and logical "leap" we can make, but it would make me more comfortable if that explicit clarification was made somewhere.

Comment: Also, that bit about the Bouncers meeting Morgan Katarn at Olmondo and subsequently leading him to the Valley of the Jedi definitely makes the whole thing fit together much more neatly and provides a nice bridge to make that (completely logical and reasonable) "leap" from my previous comment into more of a "path".