# What actually happened to the "remnants" of Lord Kaan's thought bomb?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, darth-bane

As a tangent (and somewhat dependent on the answer) to my earlier question, "**[Where on Ruusan was the Valley of the Jedi constructed in relation to the detonated thought bomb?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/245829/16186)**", after the detonation of the [thought bomb](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thought_bomb) which effectively ended the [Seventh Battle of Ruusan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Seventh_Battle_of_Ruusan), there was a physical remnant left at the site. For reference, when [Lord Kaan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Skere_Kaan) completed the thought bomb ritual, it created

> a silvery ovoid that imprisoned the spirit of every significantly Force-sensitive being within the blast radius.
>  [image: The thought bomb on Ruusan (Wookieepedia)]

However, in the events that take place in the [Dark Forces](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Dark_Forces_(novellas)) series of novellas, they only seem to refer to the [Force nexus](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Force_nexus) that was created as a later result of the weapon's use and (*apparently*) this object's existence. I've not been able to find any explicit reference to this physical object beyond the accounts outlined in the [Bane Trilogy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Bane_Trilogy). Is there any source that explains what actually happened to it? Did its physical form persist (as I would tend to believe) until at least [Jerec](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jerec_(Inquisitor))'s attempted manipulations? Or, did the eventual creation of the Force Nexus "consume" it in some way?

Answer (score 2):

In the Dark Forces/Jedi Knight games, the source of the Force Nexus is depicted as a large dome at the floor of the mausoleum:

[image: Screenshot of Dark Forces II: Jedi Knight]
(source: cutscene from [Dark Forces II: Jedi Knight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JmD-HlPAVTw))

[image: Screenshot of Jedi Knight II: Jedi Outcast]
(source: cutscene from [Jedi Knight II: Jedi Outcast](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Valley_of_the_Jedi#A_monument_to_the_Army_of_Light))

It seems like this dome is intended to have been somehow created from the thought bomb. Note the similar rock formations here, in this panel from *Jedi vs. Sith* depicting the thought bomb falling into a cave:

[image: Image from Jedi vs. Sith showing the Thought Bomb falling into an underground chamber]
(source: [Wookieepedia screenshot from *Jedi vs. Sith*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bouncer?file=Bouncers_and_the_thought_bomb.JPG))

This is corroborated by a note written by Luke in *Book of Sith*:

> Kyle Katarn, one of my students, unfolded the thought bomb's vortex at Ruusan and freed the spirits that had been trapped inside for more than a thousand years. —Luke

(*Book of Sith*, p70)

This seems to be a reference to the finale of *Jedi Knight*, in which the Jedi souls stream out of the dome:

[image: Screenshot of Dark Forces II: Jedi Knight showing souls streaming out of the dome]

*The Essential Reader's Companion* also makes reference to the thought bomb still being there, although it doesn't explicitly say it's still an orb:

> With the villains defeated, Kyle frees the spirits contained in the thought bomb, dispersing the focus of Force energy beyond the Valley and finally bringing peace to these long-tortured souls.

(*The Essential Reader's Companion*, p279)

Comment: Thank you for the excellent references/resources. My intent is still to try to determine if that physical object was actually in existence up to the point of the Dark Forces storyline, although I may have to just "fudge" it and make an assumption of my own one way or the other. Even so, the information you posted may be useful in providing some insight into my other (linked) question about the location of the thought bomb in relation to the monument.